# kernel messages + DS CPU bug present and SMT on

Tags: linux, cpu, kernel

what is the meaning of the following messages that we get from kernel messages

```
#  dmesg  | grep "MDS CPU bug"
[    0.432893] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
```

is above messages are safe ?, or need to do some actions accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel's [Security Advisor Bulletin](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/advisory/intel-sa-00233.html)
describes this CPU vulnerability as:

> Microarchitectural Store Buffer Data Sampling (MSBDS): Store buffers on some microprocessors utilizing speculative execution may allow an authenticated user to potentially enable information disclosure via a side channel with local access.

This means that if your computer was already infected, the virus might
be able to access some remnants of secret data.

As the computer must be already infected, there exist simpler methods
for the virus to access secret data. So I don't think that this is a
serious problem.

Look for a BIOS update for your motherboard. This might by itself plug
this vulnerability.

If your BIOS is already the latest available from the manufacturer's
website, see post
[How do I fix 'MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible' errors from logwatch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250040/how-do-i-fix-mds-cpu-bug-present-and-smt-on-data-leak-possible-errors-from-lo).

Be warned that the fix that is proposed will cause a huge performance
hit on multi-cpu or multi-core configurations.

> `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
>
> Change:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mds=full,nosmt"
> ```
>
> Save the file and quit `gedit`.
>
> `sudo update-grub`
>
> `reboot`

Comment: hen you say "This means that if your computer was already infected, the virus might be able to access some remnants of secret data."  , you means the effected virus is inside the RHEL 7.9 OS?

Comment: Yes, the virus needs to be running inside the computer in order to try to use this.

Comment: something isn't clear here because we have 487 data-nodes machines, and the messages from kernel as "MDS CPU bug present and SMT on" are only appears on the first 3 machines. ( the first 3 machines have 32 core ) , when all rest have 48 core , is it give you some hint?   ( we also saw that on the 3 first machine sometimes CPU idle is very low and not as on all other machines

Comment: what you think about solution as to re-install the first machines ( I mean new OS rhel 7.9 and then application )

Comment: I can't guess what makes this/these computer(s) different. If the difference is in the OS, re-installation might help. If some hardware component is different (can happen even among computers of the same model), then you are left with my answer.

Comment: the diff between 3 first machines to other is about the CPU core quantity. ( on the first 3 machine we have 32 when on all rest 48 core ) , and the  "CPU bug present and SMT on" messages are only on the first 3 machines

Comment: In this case re-installation is unlikely to solve it (but nothing is ever sure).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152136/discussion-between-king-david-and-harrymc).